# Помогите реализовать сортировку по длине слова

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть задание реализовать через паттерн стратегия два способа сортировки контейнера array  1)по алфавиту 2)по длине слов (если кол-во букв одинаковое то сортировать по алфавиту)

Первое сделал, второе даже не знаю с чего начать

```
class Sort
{
public:
virtual void sorting() = 0;
};
class SortAlphabet:public Sort
{
array<string, 5>::iterator a;
array<string, 5>::iterator b;
public:
SortAlphabet(array<string,5>::iterator p1, array<string, 5>::iterator p2):a(p1),b(p2){}
virtual void sorting()
{
    sort(a, b);
}
};
class SortCount :public Sort
{
array<string, 5>::iterator a;
array<string, 5>::iterator b;
public:
SortCount(array<string, 5>::iterator p1, array<string, 5>::iterator p2) :a(p1), b(p2) {}
virtual void sorting()
{
    /*не знаю что писать*/
}
};
  class Sorter
   {
    Sort *p;
    public:
    Sorter(Sort*p) :p(p) {}
    void sorting() { p->sorting(); }
    ~Sorter() {
        delete p;
    }
   };
   void main()
   {
    array<string, 5> a;
    cout << "Enter words:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string word;
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    Sorter*p = new Sorter(new SortAlphabet(a.begin(), a.end()));
    p->sorting();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n\n";
  }
```

Comment: так а что вам конкретно не понятно по этому заданию? Как сравнить размеры строк?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ничего не понятно.Что писать вообще

Comment: тоесть вы написали сортировку по алфавиту, но не можете сравнить два размера? Если вам так сложно представить как это будет со строками, то просто представте, что сортируете массив чисел.

Comment: посмотрел на вашу сортировку по алфавиту... А где она? Только не говорите, что вы просто взяли стандартный алгоритм сортировки из stl...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch главное работает

Comment: понятное дело работает, но вам не кажется странным использовать для задания уже готовое решиние? Тем более писать под него зачем-то целый класс? Ну раз уже пользуетесь этим алгоритмом, то для сортировки по длине строки просто добавте соответствующий предикат третьим параметром.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я извиняюсь, что такое предикат?Что конкретно написать

Comment: это функция/класс/лямбда, которая в зависимости от входных данных возвращает булево значение и не имеет скрытого состояния.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж взяли для первого задания функцию из `stl`, то вот пример решения этой же функцией 2-ого задания:

```
sort(begin_iter, end_iter, 
    [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)  
        {return a.size() < b.size();});
```

Если не знаете что такое третий параметр - это предикат выраженный лямбдой.

Comment: Есть сомнения, что человек, не знающий, что такое предикат, поймет, что такое лямбда.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Знать название - это уже пол дела) в конце концов в гугле, я думаю, его не забанили. А расписывание этих терминов не требуется вопросом, да и времени на это нет.

Comment: Ну мы тут, вроде как, гонимся за пониманием, а не просто работающим ответом, на крайний случай могли использовать указатель на функцию, а не лямбду, но дело ваше.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker указатель на функцию? Вообще-то специально для этого лямбду и изобрели. Так сразу видно, что у тебя на месте происходит, а не лезть потом куда-то смотреть что это за функция, в которой 1 строка кода. Можно было бы класс с перегруженным оператором, но опять таки - зачем, если есть лямбда?

Comment: Вы перечитайте мой первый комментарий и поймете, для чего в данной ситуации можно использовать указатель на функцию.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker вы драматизируете - лямбда не такая уж и сложная. Считай просто определение функции без прототипа. Сдесь даже не используется что-то вроде [&]() mutable{}

Comment: Не сочтите за грубость, не надо _мне_ объяснять, что такое лямбда, я знаю, что это. Проблема в том, что человек не может без stl свою сортировку написать, пусть даже простейшую. Повторюсь, это мое мнение, и я никого не заставляю использовать то или другое, на этом предлагаю сию дискуссию завершить.